# import CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to import CSV file as array in python.
I Use pandas data frames instead of numpy arrays but it fails with error

> ( there is no pandas model)

although I've installed it .
What can be the reason?

```
import pandas as pd
X= pd.read_csv("file1.csv",'r')
y= pd.read_csv("file2.csv", 'r')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
 import csv
 f1 = open('file1.csv')
 csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work  because of error "invalid mode ('r')". I try mode 'r' and 'rb' and doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried
    X= pd.read_csv("file1.csv"',header=none,sep=',')